# Cache iframe request with ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, caching, iframe, service-worker

I'm trying to cache the request of an iframe with my ServiceWorker (using sw-toolbox.js).

But no matter what I try the files are never served from the ServiceWorker as Chrome Network Tab tells me.

Here is my service-worker.js:

```
'use strict';
importScripts('./build/sw-toolbox.js');

self.toolbox.options.cache = {
    name: 'ionic-cache'
};

var static_urls = [
    'https://quiqqer.local/test?app=1',
    'https://quiqqer.local/calendar?app=1'
];

self.toolbox.precache(static_urls);

self.toolbox.router.any('/(.*)', self.toolbox.cacheFirst, {origin: 'https://quiqqer.local'});

self.addEventListener('install', function (event)
{
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.toolbox.router.default = self.toolbox.cacheFirst;
```

The self.toolbox.precache() function makes the requests to my static_urls properly, as I can see in the Network Tab.

But all the requests coming from the iframe (going to https://quiqqer.local/) seem to not being routed through the ServiceWorker.

What am I doing wrong? Or isn't it possible to cache the iframe requests?

Running on Chromium using Linux.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

There's probably an official HTML specification that provides a more canonical answer, but I'll just excerpt this from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe):

> The HTML  element represents a nested browsing context,
>   effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page. ...
>   Each browsing context has its own session history and active document.
>   The browsing context that contains the embedded content is called the
>   parent browsing context.

You can think of what's going on in an `<iframe>`, including the request to load the `<iframe>`'s `src` itself, as being equivalent to what would happen if that `<iframe>` were loaded in a separate tab. Unless the service worker controlling the parent browsing context (i.e. your top-level page) also happens to include the `<iframe>`'s `src` under its scope, that service worker won't have any control over initially loading the `<iframe>` or the requests made from the `<iframe>`.

Comment: If the page at `example.com` creates an `<iframe src="https://example.com/1.jpg">` should it have access to request and response in the parent SW? What if the domain is a subdomain like `https://static1.example.com/1.jpg`?

Comment: Creating `<iframe src="https://example.com/1.jpg">` will result in a `fetch` event for a `navigate` request, available for the SW for `example.com` to intercept. (Except why would you use a JPG as the `src` for an `<iframe>`?) That would not be the case for `https://static1.example.com/`, since it's a different origin.

Comment: `jpg` is just for the sake of an example. My use case is a legacy app where downloads are implemented as `<iframe src="...">` With source pointing to an external URL. Usually in a subdomain, sometimes in external CDN. Sometimes the response is an error. I was trying to intercept statuses of such downloads and act if it is an error. However, now as far as I understand it is not possible.