# html2canvas: use cached images from Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, html2canvas, workbox

**TL;DR:** How can images processed by html2canvas be cached using a ServiceWorker? Why the existing ServiceWorker cache isn't used?

I'm writing a PWA that also can be used offline. It's an application that is used for creating grids of custom images. Images are coming from an external API and I cache these requests to the API using Workbox/ServiceWorker.

Offline capabilities are working great, but when using **html2canvas** in order to create thumbnails of the image grids, it's **only working online**. html2canvas seems to create an iframe-copy of the page in order to create the screenshots. And **for all images** in the iframe/screenshot **new requests are done**, and the existing cache from the ServiceWorker isn't used.

This screenshot shows the network traffic for opening my app with a grid of 2 images from the API:
[image: screenshot of network traffic]

- request (1) is are the images loaded by the app - coming from ServiceWorker
- requests (2-4) are three attemts of loading the images from html2canvas, where the last one succeeds using the ServiceWorker, however the images are not visible on the screenshot.

Any ideas for making html2canvas usable offline using either the existing ServiceWorker cache or another one are welcome.

I'm using html2canvas 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used html2canvas, so I might be wrong, but if it is creating an `<iframe>`, then keep in mind that an iframe establishes a new browsing context, and that the communication between browsing contexts is severely constrained for security reasons.

The iframe created by html2canvas should be on the same origin of your PWA, so maybe you could try using the [BroadcastChannel API](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/broadcastchannel/) to let these browsing contexts (i.e. the iframe and the service worker) communicate between each other.

See also:

- [Cache iframe request with ServiceWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932169/cache-iframe-request-with-serviceworker)